# Interpretation of PP plot

Tags: python, probability, statsmodels, normal-distribution

I am playing around with PP plots in `statsmodels` and I wonder why comparing Normal distribution with scale = 5 and loc = 20 to Standard Normal distribution results in a straight line on the PP plot when the distributions are much different. Please find sample code below:

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pylab

test = np.random.normal(20, 5, 100000)

pp = sm.ProbPlot(test, loc=0, scale=1)
fig = pp.ppplot()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The probability plots currently always estimate loc and scale for the plot. This was supposed to be changed, but it hasn't happened yet. https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/3981

Comment: @Josef Thanks for pointing this out. So currently there is no way to compare two specified distributions using `sm.ProbPlot`?

Comment: I'm not sure. There might be a backdoor by setting loc, scale and/or fit_params after initializing a `sm.ProbPlot` instance. AFAIR, there is no official way of comparing with a fully specified distribution.

Comment: @Josef thanks again. So just to make it clear, by using the code above (even though I am specifying loc and scale), I am comparing a set of observations from N(20, 5) not to standard normal, but to a distribution fitted to my data (which will most likely resemble N(20, 5))?

Comment: Yes. If loc and scale are estimated from the data as in the current version, then we are essentially checking whether the data belongs to the location-scale family. e.g. `Is the data normally distributed?`, but not `Is the data normally distributed with my specified loc and scale?`.

Comment: @Josef Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to reduce the sample size and you will see the effect.

```
test = np.random.normal(20, 5, 100)

pp = sm.ProbPlot(test, loc=0, scale=1, fit=False).ppplot(line='45')
plt.show()
```

If fit is false, loc, scale, and distargs are passed to the distribution. If fit is True then the parameters for dist are fit automatically using dist.fit. The quantiles are formed from the standardized data, after subtracting the fitted loc and dividing by the fitted scale. fit cannot be used if dist is a SciPy frozen distribution.